# Baire space - probably a typo in the book

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

From the book "Topology without tears".

[image]

The proof of (i) is trivial. But in (ii) the sentence "Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of open dense subsets of $Y$". It looks to me that it should be $X$ instead of $Y$. Otherwise it is a tautology: if $X_n$ is an open dense subset of $Y$ then $\{X_n \cap Y\} = \{X_n\} \in Y$ - by assumption of the problem and we don't need to prove anything?

Comment: Each $X_i$ is open and dense (as a subset of $Y$) with respect to $\tau$.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist my point is that $X_i$ does not need to be a subset of $Y$. It should be any dense open subset of $X$.

Comment: Sure. And my point is, based on what I can tell from the text, that isn’t what the exercise is asking you to assume. Note that the interpretation I give in my last comment is enough for (ii) to not be a tautology.

Comment: @Andreo I think you are right, $Y$ should be $X$, in particular since the author asks in (iii) to use (ii). You should contact the author and point out the typo. The author will confirm if your interpretation is correct, and if so then he will correct the book (and may include your name in the list of people at the beginning that helped improve his book). His email address is in footnote 2 on the first page of the book (I just looked online at Version of February 23, 2018). http://www.topologywithouttears.net/